# Intrinsic Parity of the $^+$ Meson

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, parity, mesons, pions

Why it is not possible to determine intrinsic parity of the $^+$ mesons from the $^+ → ^+ ^0$ decay?

Comment: Note to the downvoter: just because a question is short does not mean it's insufficient. (although of course I don't actually know why somebody downvoted this)

Answer (score 2):

Does the "parity violation" section of the [kaon wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon) answer your question?

To summarize: back in the day when it was thought (from purely aesthetic considerations) that all interactions conserved parity, there was "some particle" (that would eventually become the charged Kaon) which decayed to $\pi^+ +\pi^0$. The final state had parity +1, and so that particle had parity +1. But it was also found that "another particle" decayed $\pi^+ +\pi^++\pi^-$. And that second particle had the exact same lifetime and charge - which simply proves that it's the same particle. Two different particles having the same lifetime but decaying to a completely different set of particles is not something that can be imposed by any kind of symmetry trick.

Then it was found [in the Wu experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment) that parity is not conserved in the weak interactions, and these decays were no longer so mysterious. The kaons only decay weakly (both final states have different strangeness than the charged kaons). So parity is not conserved in this decay, which is why it decays to two different parities and why you cannot determine the intrinsic parity from the decay products.